# Red5 vs BlazeDS

Tags: java, flash, blazeds, red5

What technology are better (robust, stable, speed) for rich web app with flash movies, chat, etc.
Somebody said that Red5 will drop down if more that 50 users try to suck video stream from it.
Is there people who use Java on server side and Flash for client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red5 is a server which supports video streaming, messaging (through sharedobject) and remoting but is used mainly for video streaming. BlazeDS is used for messaging, remoting and pushing data from the server to the client. So for video streaming Red5 is winner because you cannot do that in BlazeDS.

If you plan to use only remoting BlazeDS can be a better option, in my opinion the product is mature and used by a very large number of Flex/Java developers

Comment: 10x a lot. As I understand if we don`t need media streams BlaszeDS more robust with a lot of requests.

Comment: We have some "DS" type features in Red5 as well, btw.